# problem with connecting Clever Cloud bucket to django with envronment variable

Tags: python, django, bucket

I have a problem to connect my CC bucket to a Django application. My bucket looks as follows:

[image]

Could you please tell me what I have to define as CC_FS_BUCKET? I thought it is: folder:addon-id.host

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot it seems you are using a Cellar addon. This is used for object storage, not fs-bucket. 
FS-bucket addons on the other hand are used for filesystem. If you create an fs-bucket addon you will find the value you need for the CC_FS_BUCKET variable.